# Pasting all prior elements of a column as of a row with the highest score

Tags: r, data.table, concatenation, paste

This is what my data-frame looks like:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- fread('
    Product   Score    Description
    A          1         aapl 
    A          2         banana 
    A          3         orange
    B          1         coke
    B          2         pepsi
    C          1         butter
    D          1         milk 
')
```

I am trying to get the max score of each product and concatenate all the Descriptions prior to that row with max score so the output looks like this:

```
  Product   Score(Max)    Description2
    A          3         aapl;banana;orange
    B          2         coke;pepsi
    C          1         butter
    D          1         milk
```

I have tried

```
    dt[,Description2 := as.character(ifelse(!max(Score),NA,paste(shift(Description,1),
Description,sep=";"))),by=Product]
```

Your help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We group by 'Product', get the `max` of 'Score' and `paste` the 'Description' together with `collapse = ";"`.

```
dt[, .(ScoreMax = max(Score), Description2 = paste(Description, collapse=";")), 
          by = .(Product)]
#   Product ScoreMax       Description2
#1:       A        3 aapl;banana;orange
#2:       B        2         coke;pepsi
#3:       C        1             butter
#4:       D        1               milk
```

---

Using `:=` (assignment) creates a new column in the initial dataset.  For summarisation, we can keep it in a `list` or just use `.(` after grouping by the variable.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! What is the purpose of the period infront of Product like .(Product)?

Comment: @gibbz00  There is no need for that.  You can just use `by = Product`.  But, I used that for general purpose in case you have more than one grouping variable.  It is otherwise `by = list(Product)`